# Hitting a "generic not constrained error" when it is clearly constrained

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

[Here is a link to a playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c27780a771c8278626f9868c7a7cd7d1)

This is the code (stripped down for readability):

```
#[async_trait]
impl <'a, FUNC, CONTEXT, PARAM, RETURN, FUT> StepWithParams<CONTEXT, PARAM, RETURN> for FUNC 
where 
    FUNC: FnOnce(&'a PARAM) -> FUT + Send + Sync, 
    FUT: Future<Output = Result<RETURN, ErrTypes>> + Send + Sync,
    PARAM: Send + Sync,
    CONTEXT: Send + Sync,
    RETURN: Send + Sync,
{

    async fn run_user_step (self, request_context: &'a CONTEXT) -> Result<RETURN, ErrTypes> {
        let param = PARAM::from_context(request_context);
        self(param).await
    }
}
```

A full version is linked in the playground. Compiling this will generate a compiler error as follows:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `FUT` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  --> src/main.rs:22:41
   |
22 | impl <'a, FUNC, CONTEXT, PARAM, RETURN, FUT> StepWithParams<CONTEXT, PARAM, RETURN> for FUNC 
   |                                         ^^^ unconstrained type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0207`.
```

However, isn't the generic parameter clearly constrained?

Comment: It's related to the lifetime of the reference in the `FnOnce` argument type: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/86934

Answer (score -1):

From the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/implementations.html#generic-implementations) :

> Generic parameters constrain an implementation if the parameter appears at least once in one of:
>
> - The implemented trait, if it has one
> - The implementing type
> - As an associated type in the bounds of a type that contains another parameter that constrains the implementation

Since you're writing a blanket implementation the second two bullets aren't relevant (unless you add additional trait bounds to FUNC I suppose). So you need to add FUT to the trait definition, meaning the impl block starts:

```rust
impl <'a, FUNC, CONTEXT, PARAM, RETURN, FUT> StepWithParams<CONTEXT, PARAM, RETURN, FUT> for FUNC
```

With a couple of other tidy-ups guided by the compiler you end up with this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad2a37ab4ce6d7e0afc8ee75169f125b)

The [error code details](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0207.html) and [original RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0447-no-unused-impl-parameters.md) that the error details link to also give some more background.

Comment: The last two bullets are definitely relevant. `FUT` should be constrained because of the third one.